# Can we fetch the depth of taxonomy from term load

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8, entities

Term::load (termid) can we get the depth of term. If yes how can we achieve ? If no, how can we achieve this without loading tree nor children is there any other way we can fetch depth?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use TermStorage loadTree function. It will load the whole tree and the depths of each term will be avaiable.
2. A much more cleaner / efficient way can be to use the "taxonomy_term_hierarchy" table, (database service, select..). You query over and over again till the "parent" (or current examined) term parent is 0.

If you really feel you are being lost, take a look on [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/886526) thread.